# Cross entropy loss returns infinity in neural network

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, loss-function, cross-entropy

I am implementing a neural network and using a cross-entropy loss function. 
Cross entropy error is given by:

`error = - np.sum((actual_Y * np.log2 (Y_pred)) + ((1-actual_Y)* np.log2 (1 - Y_pred)))`

after few iterations `(1- Y_pred)` inside `np.log2()`start returning `-inf`.

why it happens and what is its solution?
It is obvious `log2(0)` is `-inf` but how to overcome it.

Comment: Could you kindly provide the values for y_pred and actual_y for the first (until inf is reached) iterations (i.e. every time loss is calculated)?

Comment: y_pred is approximately 1 and actual_y is 1 too. and iterations (i.e. every time loss calculated, i.e. number of epochs)